# Availability Calendar Errors on Mon 31 Mar 2014

Tags: mysql, calendar, datepicker

I am creating a page to display the availability of holiday lettings. After much learning (a newbie) I created the following code to display availability. Its objective is to display a calendar table in a line across the page and fill in booked dates (note: final version takes dates from a MySQL table).
It works fine unless the start date is Mon 31 Mar 2014 or later. I am sure I have missed something obvious but can not work out where the error is. Any help much appreciated.

```
<?php 
 $calendarstart = mktime(0,0,0,12,01,13);//Calendar Start as a Unix Timestamp
 $calendarend = mktime(0,0,0,5,18,14); //Calendar End as a Unix Timestamp
   echo "<table border='1' width='800' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' align='center'>
     <tr>
         <th colspan='31' align='center' >December 2013</th>
         <th colspan='31' align='center'>January 2014</th>
         <th colspan='28' align='center'>February 2014</th>
         <th colspan='31' align='center'>March 2014</th>
         <th colspan='30' align='center'>April 2014</th>
         <th colspan='18' align='center'>May 2014</th>
     </tr>"; 
      echo "<tr>";
       for ($count=$calendarstart; $count<=($calendarend); ($count=$count+86400)) // loop to add 1 day to Calendar
           {
           $startdate= (date(strtotime("Sun 30 Mar 2014"))); //Start Date from MYSQL Table Record as a Unix Timestamp      
           $enddate= (date(strtotime("Thu 10 Apr 2014"))); //End Date from MYSQL Table Record as a Unix Timestamp 


            if ($startdate==$count) // Is Recordset start date the same as the Calendar  
              {
              echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FF0000'>".date("D d ",$count)."<br>"; // make cell background red and write date in  
              $duration=$startdate+86400; // set variable to count duration
              $durationend=$enddate;
              }
            elseif ($duration==$count) 
              {
                  if ($duration<$durationend)
                  {
                  echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FF0000' >".date("D d ",$count)."<br>"; // make cell background red and write date in  
                     if ($count<($durationend-86400))
                     {
                     $duration=$duration+86400; // add 1 day
                     } 
                  }

               }
             else
               {
               echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>".date("D d ",$count)."<br>"; //make cell background white and write date in
               } 

              }
     echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: It does not fill the cell in red if the date is 31 March or beyond.

Comment: After looking at what the timestamp shows, I'm wondering if it is to do with daylight saving which changes on 30 March?

Comment: I managed to get this to work by adding an hour on 30 March. 
          
Is there a different way of making up for the daylight saving hour?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for changing hour on last March Sunday. 31 March 2014 is the first monday after changing hour. The problem repeats every year, on the first Monday after changing hour.
I don´t now if this is a server problem or a code problem.
And I don`t now if on April, for example, the problem will be with the first Monday after changing hour on October.